# About vector valued measure algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $A$ be a Banach algebra. By $L^1(G,A)$ and $M(G,A)$ we denote the $A$-valued group, and measure algebra.

1. Is $M(G,A)$ a Banach algebra (with convolution as the product)?
2. Let $B$ be a Banach algebra contains $A$ as an ideal. Is $L^1(G,A)$ an ideal of $M(G,B)$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the _exact_ definitions of $L^1(G,A)$ and (especially) $M(G,A)$.  Can you give some references and/or explanation?

Comment: @MatthewDaws $L^1(G,A)$ is indeed the projective tensor product of $L^1(G)$ and $A$. Another space is defined for example in the book titled "Vector Mesures" written by N. DINCULEANU (https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781483197623/vector-measures).